# Bloodborne New Game Plus difficulty jumps

Tags: bloodborne

I am wondering if anybody has figured out the difficulty jumps in the New Game+.

1. Is there a certain amount of restarts/"pluses" where difficulty stops increasing?
2. Also, If it is known, just how much do the enemy stats grow with each NG+? I feel like on NG+ (first NG+) enemies were dealing double the damage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to http://bloodborne.wiki.fextralife.com/New+Game+Plus a user (ublug) has found that blood echo drops from bosses scale according to the following:

```
ng++ = 10% more than ng+
ng+3 = 25% more than ng+
ng+4 = 50% more than ng+
ng+5 = 100% more than ng+
ng+6 = 150% more than ng+
```

I was unable to find any other quantitative evidence about scaling between the levels.

One may try to extrapolate from this data that enemies will be 10% harder to kill and will deal 10% more damage on ng++ compared to ng+. A similar approach could be taken by estimating  boss health at each level of ng+ to estimate the scaling, but this does not seem entirely correct.

If we look at the design of Dark Souls 1, we see the following http://darksouls.wikidot.com/new-game-plus

> A single formula cannot be applied to the increase in enemy HP and
>   Souls between NG and NG+. This is because they increase by
>   inconsistent amounts, usually corresponding to the location. In NG+,
>   enemy HP is usually between roughly 1.5x to 2.5x of NG values, while
>   souls dropped are usually between 2x to 5x NG values. There are
>   exceptions.

There is likely a similar system in place for Bloodborne.

Dark Souls 1 also featured a cap in difficulty upon restarting:

> After the seventh playthrough is completed, the game will no longer
>   increase in difficulty after it restarts. NG+7 and any subsequent
>   playthroughs are a repeat of NG+6. It is a common misconception that
>   NG+7 is the highest difficulty.

The same cap existed in Dark Souls 2.